# Why does PHP rowCount not work with SQLite?

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, pdo

I wrote an application in PHP using MySQL.

Lately I see no need for MySQL, so I converted the database to SQLite using a converter, and converted my PDO to use SQLite.

Mostly it *worked out of the box*, but for any pages that access rowCount they die.

### Example code that breaks page - 1

```
  <?php
    $dbh = new PDO('sqlite:database.sqlite');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM events";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute();

    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { ?>
    <select class="form-control" name="id">
      <?php foreach ($results as $row) { ?>
        <option class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['fn'] . " " . $row['sn'] . " (" . $row['sd'] . " - " . $row['ed'] . ")";?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  <?php } ?>
```

### Example code that breaks page - 2

```
  <?php
  function user_is_admin()
  {
    $dbh = new PDO('sqlite:database.sqlite');
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE un = :un AND ia = 1");
    $stmt->bindParam(":un", $_SESSION['user']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $total = $stmt->rowCount();

    if ( $total == 1 ) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  ?>
```

This kills the page and nothing loads under it.

Why is this?

I thought PDO is universal, like the same code can be used with MySQL, SQLite etc.

What should I use?

Comment: See the manual on [`rowCount`](http://php.net/pdostatement.rowCount); it's only guaranteed to work for UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE with each driver.

Comment: "If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications." -- [PDO docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php). See [example 2](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#example-1010) on that page for a workaround.

Comment: For the first, couldn't you check `count($results)` instead?  For the second reform the query to be `SELECT COUNT(*)...` and use that value as the `$total` variable?